# Add SVG images to resource file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, svg, devexpress

I think this issue transcends Dev Express, which is why I haven't gone to the vendor's forum just yet (although I could be wrong).  In the latest release of Dev Express Winforms (17.2), there is support for SVG images on the ribbon bar items.  When you use the Dev Express picker and add them to project resources, it looks like this:

[image]

I have some SVG images of my own I'd like to add.  Dragging and dropping them adds them as files.  Doing an import through the designer adds them to the form resources, and I want them as project resources (we reuse icons across multiple forms).

Is there an easy way to add local SVG images to my Resources File and have them visible to all controls within the project, the way the Dev Express gallery images are?

If not, is there a hard way?

Comment: As of DevExpress version 19.1, there is now built-in support for custom SVG images!  https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/117631/Common-Features/Graphics-Performance-and-High-DPI/How-To-Draw-and-Use-SVG-Images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the [SvgImageCollection](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.Utils.SvgImageCollection.class) component which specially designed to store vector images for DevExpress controls.
You can invoke the SvgImageCollection's smart tag and click "Edit Collection" to invoke the Collection Editor dialog. Use the "Add" selector to choose where to import SVG images from:
[image: adding SVG images]

Comment: I can't quite get the sizing right on the ribbon, but this is definitely promising.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if something has changed or if something has happened in the last three years, but this is now super easy -- barely an inconvenience.

To add an SVG to the resources, go to the `ImageOptions.SvgImage` property of any control, Click on the properties (ellipsis) button, and it will bring up this familiar form:

[image]

The "import" button will allow you to add local SVGs into the resource file, which can then be accessed by the entire project.